# How to use Sealed Class Data from Flow in Swift in Kotlin Mutliplatform Mobile?

Tags: ios, swift, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile

I unable to access the sealed class data observed in a Flow from Swift ..

```
sealed class NetworkStatus<T> {

data class Loading<T>(var loading: Boolean) : NetworkStatus<T> ()

data class CustomSignal<T>(var signal: String) : NetworkStatus<T>()

data class CustomSignalDetailed<T>(var signal: ErrorCaseData) : NetworkStatus<T>()

data class Failure<T>(val e: Throwable) : NetworkStatus<T>()

data class Data<T> (val data: T ) : NetworkStatus<T>()

companion object {

    fun <T>loading(isLoading: Boolean): NetworkStatus<T> = Loading(isLoading)

    fun <T> customstatus(signal: String): NetworkStatus<T> = CustomSignal(signal)

    fun <T> customStatusDetailed(signals: ErrorCaseData): NetworkStatus<T> = CustomSignalDetailed(signals)

    fun <T> failure(e: Throwable): NetworkStatus<T> = Failure(e)

    fun <T> data(data: T): NetworkStatus<T> = Data<T>(data)
    }

}
```

https://gist.github.com/RageshAntony/a4fd357973485b5fb8aef0e189ee9e7e

In the above gist ....

In MainActivity.kt , I used sealed class in flow for Data

Now I need the same in Swift but it's confusing

Even I used something as CFlow wrapping.. still confusion

In Swift , I can't get object type only as nsarray and also NetworkStatus.data is not accessible

.. I tried manual typecast (in line 8 , contentview.swift )

Still data object don't have any type ...

Please help me how to implement the same flow in Swift like in MainActivity.kt

Comment: Can you please provide the header definition of the kotlin native library generated for iOS? Specifically, the definition related to `NetworkStatus`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start from this sealed class declared in the shared code:

```kotlin
sealed class KMMResult<out Value>

data class SuccessKMMResult<Value>(
    val value: Value
): KMMResult<Value>()

data class ErrorKMMResult<Value>(
    val throwable: Throwable
): KMMResult<Value>()
```

and this method that randomly returns you a `KMMResult` with Success or Failure:

```kotlin
fun getRandomIntWrappedInResult(): KMMResult<Int> {
    val isSuccess = Random.nextBoolean()
    return if(isSuccess) {
      SuccessKMMResult(Random.nextInt(until = 10))
    } else {
        ErrorKMMResult(RuntimeException("There was an error, Int not generated"))
    }
}
```

You can use it like this on Android:

```kotlin
val randomInt: KMMResult<Int> = getRandomIntWrappedInResult()
val randomIntText: String = when (randomInt) {
    is KMMResult.ErrorKMMResult -> {
        "Error: ${randomInt.throwable.message}"
    }
    is KMMResult.SuccessKMMResult -> {
        "Success: ${randomInt.value}"
    }
}
```

and like this on iOS:

```swift
let randomInt: KMMResult<KotlinInt> = RandomNumberGeneratorKt.getRandomIntWrappedInIntResult()
let randomIntText: String

switch randomInt {
case let error as KMMResultErrorKMMResult<KotlinInt>:
    randomIntText = "Error: \(error.throwable.message ?? error.throwable.description())"
case let success as KMMResultSuccessKMMResult<KotlinInt>:
    randomIntText = "Success: \(success.value)"
default:
    randomIntText = "This never happens"
}
```

This is not the best solution, I suggest you to create a Swift enum like:

```swift
enum SwiftResult<Value> {
  case error(String)
  case success(Value)
}
```

and convert `KMMResult` to `SwiftResult` using:

```swift
func toSwiftResult<Value>(kmmResult: KMMResult<Value>) -> SwiftResult<Value> {
  if let successResult = kmmResult as? KMMResultSuccessKMMResult<Value> {
    return SwiftResult.success(successResult.value!)
  }
  if let errorResult = kmmResult as? KMMResultErrorKMMResult {
    return SwiftResult.error(errorResult.throwable.message ?? errorResult.throwable.description())
  }
  return SwiftResult.error("Unexpected error converting to SwiftResult")
}
```

Unfortunately, you need to do this manually for each sealed class, so I suggest you to use the library [moko-kswift](https://github.com/icerockdev/moko-kswift) that does this job for you.

P.S. Avoid use `List<Something>` as a generic type because `Something` will be erased and when seeing the type from Swift you will just see `NSArray`. You can use two classes, one for single item and one for List, still generic on `Something`, or you can create a wrapper data class around your list, say `ListWrapper`, so the type won't be erased, because your original `List<Something>` would be inside `ListWrapper` which will be the type for `NetworkStatus`.
So use `NetworkStatus<ListWrapper<Something>>` instead of `NetworkStatus<List<Something>>`

Another P.S. Your function `getAllCategories()` in the gist is returning a `flow`, so it shouldn't be a `suspend` function.

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer. Lot of new things here.

Comment: I am currently use moko-kswift which generates things automatically . But thanks for your dedication !